# Registering a script multiple times

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the code behind, I register a startup script as below:

```
  string strFunctionName = "ShouldAdd";
  sb.Append(strFunctionName + @"((blnShouldAdd ? "true" : "false") + ", true);");

  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "shouldAdd", sb.ToString(), true);
```

This piece of code is called twice, once in Page Load when `blnShouldAdd` evaluates to `false` and in the event handler of a button when `blnShouldAdd` evaluates to `true`.

Strangely, when I debug the code and step into the ShouldAdd JS function, the value is always false. I would assume it to be true as the second call in the event handler overrides the first one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be using the `IsStartupScriptBlockRegistered()` or `IsClientScriptBlockRegistered()` method to check if the script has already been added and only bother to `RegisterStartupScript` when it returns `false`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you have to pass the complicated "this" and "this.GetType()" parameters to the `RegisterStartupScript()` function is to make sure that a given function is only registered one time.  Thus, your code runs once, not twice.

Comment: By "your code runs once," I assume you mean the JS function executes once. This is fine by me as long as it executes with the parameters that are set the 2nd time. I don't see this happening

Comment: Another example of Microsoft carefully planning ahead to break your expectations. The script will be fixed by the first register, you need to make sure you only register it once (or register it as desired the first time).

Answer (score 1):

Page Load also runs when you click the button, as part of the asp.net page lifecycle, and it runs before the button's event handler.
So, when you reach the button's event handler you already registered the script in Page Load, so the request to register another script with the same (type, key) pair is ignored.

Maybe you should move the call from Page Load to a later point of the pag lifecycle, maybe PreRender in a better place.