# Call javascript code afer postback from an update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax, postback, scriptmanager

I read [tis post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911679/registering-a-script-multiple-times)

but my problem still there. I try to execute a javascript multiple time on post back, and the script only execute the first time the page load.

To make sure the script is register after each post back i use a guid for the javascript key name.

```
var xyz = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
  string script = @"BrokerCustomValue.value='" + CustomValueToBrokerListSerialized + "';alert('" + xyz + "');";
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), script, true);
```

I need to precise that my post back event fire after a click on a link button in an update panel. If i put my link butto directly in the page it's working

Comment: What does your Page_Load method look like? I.e. where does this code fit into it?

Comment: I put my register script in the protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e). I already try it into the page load and not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solutions.

When you use an update panel and whant register script, you need to user updatePanel, and updatepanel type in param of the registerstartupscript

like this :

```
var xyz = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
  string script = @"BrokerCustomValue.value='" + CustomValueToBrokerListSerialized + "';alert('" + xyz + "');";
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(_updPanel, _updPanel.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), script, true);
```